# Passing a path in a PHP CLI script argument

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm writing a php CLI script that accepts, among other argument, a path.

So an example is:

```
php myscript.php -p=/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/andrea/samples
```

The script has his own way to red the arguments and it properly gets the value for -p, setting it in a variable called $project_path.

However, when I test the folder with isdir($project_path) it returns false.

I've tried to pass the path in different ways:

- /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/andrea/samples
- '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/andrea/samples'
- "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/andrea/samples"
- '/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/andrea/samples'
- "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/andrea/samples"

Non of them works.
What's the format I must use to make it work?
Please consider that the script must also work on different OS (i.e. Windows).

> The problem is the path argument is automatically escaped:
>   I need to unescape it.
>   The returned string is:
>
> \'/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/andrea/samples\'

Comment: And `isdir($project_path)` works if you hard-code it in your variable? Either of the quoted strings looks fine for common shells. How does the variable content look after passing them in? Else you might still wanna look into your argv reader.

Comment: You want to be able to access that argument though the `$argv` variable in php?

Comment: Try calling you script like this `php -f myscript.php -- -p=/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/andrea/samples`. The -- will tell the the php executable, that it's argument list has ended and everything after that should be passed to the PHP file. In the beginning of myscript.php do a `var_dump($argv); exit();`  and check what is coming in to your script. If index 1 of $argv is `-p=/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/andrea/samples` you're good to go.

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev: The issue is not how to read arguments: see my update.

Comment: @mario: you're right. I didn't notice that the string is actually escaped as \'/Volumes/Macintosh\\ HD/Users/andrea/samples\'
I have no idea of how to unescape it though.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? Check if magic quotes is on (http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). P.S. unescaping is done with `stripslashes()`, but you should be sure that's really what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Long answer:

```
chmod +x yourscript.php
```

-

```
$path = '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/andrea/samples';
$cmdline = sprintf('/home/user/yourscript.php -p=%s 2>&1', escapeshellarg($path));
$output = shell_exec($cmdline);
```

Example cli script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

fwrite(STDOUT, print_r($_SERVER, TRUE));

exit(0); // exit with exit code 0

?>
```

Comment: Actually I need to "unescape" the arguments, since the script is called from the terminal: they are already escaped.

Comment: The arguments should be automatically unescaped inside your script. The linux shell do that. You can test it with my example. The $_SERVER variable hold the unescaped arguments. If you really need a unescape funtion you can write it using strtr(). Important to say is that single quotes and double quotes have different meanings. To unescape single quoted arguments just strtr() "\x27\x5C\x27\x27" => "\x27". escapeshellarg() create single quoted arguments, so the example should work for you. To unescape double quoted arguments look in google and find out which characters need to be strtr'ed.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used the `getopt()` to get unescaped arguments (I don't know why there is this difference) and `str_replace( array( "'", '"'), '', $file_path );` to remove the wrapping quotes.